# grep with star symbol

Tags: linux, unix, grep

What is the difference between grep commands:

```
grep text* ==> does not give any result
grep text * ==> gives result
```

and what is different if I search text as "text".

Comment: Please show the full `grep` commands you ran, and maybe a sample of what you are searching (not my downvote).

Comment: The star is being expanded by the shell, not grep. Hence the last line searches text "text" from all files in the current directory while the first line searches whatever the shell expansion of "text*" produces (assuming there are at least two files matching the glob "text*" in the current working directory where the command is being run).

Comment: have you gone through some basic grep tutorials/doc? here's one https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/grep/topics see also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/grep/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` requires (at least) two arguments -- what you are searching for, and where you are searching for it.  If the second argument is not provided, then it will use `stdin` instead.

`grep text*` is waiting for `stdin` to provide it something to search through.

`grep text *` is searching through all the files in the current directory and returning the results.